# how to send in swagger multer file with body combined

Tags: nestjs, swagger

i have a nest js project with an endpoint that accepts files with body.
it works with postman, but
when i add swagger @ApiParam , it doesnt send the files to the field

my endpoint:

```
@ApiParam({ name: 'body', type: SendMessageParamsBody, description: 'body params ...' })
    @ApiParam({ name: 'attachments', type: 'file', description: 'file attachments' })
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'send email' })
    @ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'sends email - main end point ' })
    @Post('send-email')
    @UseGuards(ThrottlerGuard)
    @UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
        {name: 'attachments', maxCount: 4}, //must be same as the field name
    ]))
    async sendEmail(@Body() body: SendMessageParamsBody,
                    @UploadedFiles() attachments: {attachment: Express.Multer.File[]},   //undefined when not passed
    ): Promise<MyApiResponse> {
        return await this.notificationService.handleSendMessageRequest(body, attachments?.attachments, MediumType.EMAIL)
    }
```

i dont receive any files.

tried to add as abdul suggested

```
@ApiBody({
schema: {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    attachments: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'binary',
    },
  },
},
})
```

but the attachments were still undefined when passed something in the attachments field [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWhfx.png)

also m id like it to be a file chooser.

any idea how to make the swagger pass files to the 'attachments' field which chooser?
thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ApiBody` decorator on the controller to enable file uploads in swagger.

You can define your properties in the body in your case it is `attachment`.

```
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@ApiBody({
schema: {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    file: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'binary',
    },
  },
},
}) 
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
```

This is how it will be shown in the swagger. ***(Make sure to reload swagger)***
[image: Swagger Image]

You can read more about this in the official documentation of [ApiBody](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/operations#file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I have and endpoint in my project as you want. This is my code:

```
 @Post('uploadDocFile')
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Insert a new file as a part of multipart/form-data.',
  })
  @ApiResponsesCreate(DocFile, 'Document')
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  @Auth(ValdidRoles.ADMIN, ValdidRoles.METEO)
  uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() createDocDto: CreateDocFileDto,
    @GetUser() user: User,
  ) {
    return this.docFileService.createFromFile(createDocDto, file, user);
  }
```

I think you are missing  `@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')`

This is how that endpoint is displayed on swagger:
[image]

Hopes it helps,
Best regards
Lazaro

Answer (score 0):

the issue was 2 things:

1. i used fileFieldsInterceptor but you need to use:
   @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('attachments'))
2. you need to add the file into the dto of the controller to enable swagger render it as file chooser.,

```
@Post('upload')
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
upload(
  @Body() dto: SampleDto,
  @UploadedFiles() files: Express.Multer.File[],
) {
  return {
    dto,
    files: files?.map((f) => f.buffer.toString()),
  };
}

export default class SampleDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'string',
    required: false,
    title: 'fields',
    description: 'fields to aggregate',
  })
  field: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'file',
    name: 'files',
    format: 'binary',
  })
  files: Express.Multer.File[];
}
```